# Connecting an Android application to a database

Tags: php, android, database, database-connection

I need to connect my mobile app to a database so it can send information from the app to the database.

I have looked at a ton of tutorials but they seem to irrelevant to my situation or write the entire application in XML. Can I connect it through script tags in the app or do I need to connect to via PHP and if I do where do I place that file in the application?

Comment: Not 100%, but 95% that you cant connect directly to database from any mobile platform (except of course, inapp db, like sqlite), you must use a webservice. You need to put the PHP (or the language you want) in a server, and connect via webservice with that script.

Comment: In which database you want to store your data, in android system database called 'SQLite' or in any MySQL database on remote server?

Comment: Vikas - I am currently using PHPMyAdmin

Comment: Vertig0 - How exactly does it connect to the mobile app if the php script is only in the server. I have a script ready to go from tutorials I was trying to follow but I can't see how it would connect.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me if  it is a local database on your phone or not.

If it is a local database on your phone I would use [android's api](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/package-summary.html).

If it is not, the best option is to write a SOAP or Rest service which need to run on a server. Personally I would go for a REST service, because it is less complicated. Although if there is sensitive data it might be better to use a SOAP service. You might take a look at [this.](http://blog.smartbear.com/apis/understanding-soap-and-rest-basics/)

For calling your Rest services you could use a httpwebrequest. I belief [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-an-http-request-with-android) is an good example.

Answer (score 0):

Write ur database related code in php and from your app send the post or get parametized url so it can be stored to ur phpmyadmin db

Comment: I'm assuming to send the jQuery information I would need to store that information in a php variable and from there send it to the storage location in the database. Is that correct?

Comment: use volley library to send ur data to server and do what ever you want with data... check volley library in android